# SVN / Subversion copy another users directory over existing directory

Tags: svn

Ok short and curly version. I have a Subversion Repository with 4 users of which I am one of the ones with admin priv's (yea I know surprisingly). What I need to do is make a mirror copy of someone else directory over mine, but Im not quite sure how to achieve that. Is there any quick commands to do so? Well quick in concept..

All in all I just need to get rid of my files currently in the repo and take a copy of all the files in theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I just don't understand what is "someone else directory" in case of SVN repo, but if you repository tree seems like this

```
REPOROOT
  User1Dir
    Dir1
    Dir2
...
  User4
    Dir1
...
```

than copy any part of tree inside of repo into any other location is as easy as using `svn copy FromURL ToURL` with needed options